# Displaying outgoing calls in Recents without CallKit UI

Tags: ios, callkit

Is it possible to display outgoing calls from a VoIP app in Recents while using app's calling UI?

I call provider's `reportOutgoingCallWithUUID:startedConnectingAtDate:`, `reportOutgoingCallWithUUID:connectedAtDate:`, `reportCallWithUUID:endedAtDate:reason:` and `reportCallWithUUID:updated:` (to set the name). I see events in Console like

> Provider  was notified that outgoing call with UUID 
>   started connecting at date (null)
>   Provider  was asked to report that call with UUID  updated with update  .
>   Provider  was notified that
>   outgoing call with UUID  connected at date (null)
>   Provider  was asked to report that call with UUID  ended at date (null) with reason 2
>   Provider  was notified that call
>   with UUID  ended at date (null) with private reason 2

but Recents is not affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was thinking that reporting events to provider should be enough for call to appear in Recents. It turned out that I need to request transaction with `CXStartCallAction` anyway. And there's no problem with UI (I was confused by docs saying "For incoming and outgoing calls, CallKit displays the same interfaces as the Phone app", it doesn't).

Found a [clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50286809/318664) on the opposite problem and regarding incoming calls, but helpful.